Pattern rules in make, old vs. modern format
I am dealing with some makefiles that were written with the old-fashioned pattern rule format:
.c.o:
      $(CC) ....
.F90.o:
      $(F90) ...

Is there any functional difference between this format and the modern format
%.o: %.c
      $(CC) ....
%.o: %.F90
      $(F90) ...

or is it just in the looks of the code?

As your answer explains in more detail, this is not well characterized as a difference between older and newer alternatives.  GNU make has supported pattern rules (which you mis-identify as "modern") for a very long time, but this is a GNU specific feature, and not all makes are GNU make.  Not even all of them with present-day relevance.

This:
.c.o:
        $(CC) ....

is not a pattern rule, it's a suffix rule.  The differences between them are:
Suffix rules are defined by the POSIX spec for make so they are present in every POSIX-conforming implementation of make.  Pattern rules are a feature of GNU Make and aren't present in other versions of make.  So if you want portability across make you should use suffix rules.  However, remember that POSIX defines only a small subset of useful features so it may well be that you need other non-standard facilities as well anyway.
Pattern rules are much more flexible, since suffix rules can only match suffixes.  Pattern rules can match more complex things like foo%bar.x or similar.
In particular, suffix rules cannot be used to match files in other directories.  So $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c is a valid pattern but this cannot be expressed using suffix rules.
Suffix rules have a kind of strange requirement that the suffixes be defined, else it becomes just a normal rule.  Confusing, but standardized.

And POSIX's present stance is: "Consideration was given to adding metarules to the POSIX make. This would make %.o: %.c the same as .c.o:. This is quite useful and available from some vendors, but it would cause too many changes to this make to support."
